# Vimeo player restful api documentation

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am looking at a dart library that hits a specific vimeo url...

[https://player.vimeo.com/video/{videoId}/config](https://player.vimeo.com/video/%7BvideoId%7D/config)

Hitting this url returns a json file with a lot of fields. I am trying to find any docs that give a description of all of these fields. I have been unable to do so at this point.

When I got to the Vimeo API reference, it refers to language specific apis like the python api or the javascript api, not the restful api (or at least the portion I am looking for).

Does anyone know how to find docs that refer to the json returned from the previously listed URL?

Comment: Did you ever find official information about the `/config` endpoint you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to go to the API reference docs:
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#search_videos

On that page you can scroll down and review the Response (there are three areas to click: Details, Example and Reference). You want reference.